# PHP return data from EXCEL which is not saved in DB with for-each function()

Tags: php, sql, excel, foreach, spreadsheet

I am inserting the data from EXCEL in DB with the help of PHP and spreadsheet.
I already saved some `SKU` in the database, I want if SKU is saved in DB then we can add excel data in DB. else echo the SKU from excel which is not saved in DB but available in Excel.

Overall, I want to echo that SKU code is not saved in DB and available in Excel sheet while insert in DB.

I am using this code -

```
  $file_type = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($file_name);
  $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($file_type);
    
  $spreadsheet = $reader->load($file_name);
 
  unlink($file_name);

  $data = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
  
  foreach($data as $key=>$row){
    if($key > 0 ){
        $stmt =  $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `sku` = :sku");
        $stmt->execute(array(':sku' => $row[1]));
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
            foreach($result as $data) {
             //INSERT FUNCTION HERE
            } else {
               echo "Some product SKU is not matching with DB SKU - ";  //echo which SKU is not maching from EXCEL 
               exit();
            }
        } else {
            echo "Insert product name first...";
            exit();
        }
     }
```

table name `products`

```
--------------------
| id | product_sku |
--------------------
| 1  | 123456      |
--------------------
| 2  | 145236      |
--------------------
| 3  | 256314      |
--------------------
```

Excel Sheet

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with this code exactly?

Comment: You check for your `SKU` here `if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {`, so I think in this else you have to print `not found SKU in DB`